# Faint Sidebar Line and Height Issue

Tags: css, html, wordpress

I know I can't get much help here because I'm using a premium theme, bu their forums aren't that good. Anyways, I'm having problems with my site Humblesolutions4u.com I'm using elegant estate. I'm sure it's very easy, im just having a brain fart.

Problem 1: I disabled the sidebar, but there is still a faint line running down the main listing area on the homepage. I'm guessing it's an image?
Problem 2: The first 2 listings are the same height, while the third is a bit shorter! I've attached an image so you can see what I'm talking about.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What kind of tweaks have you tried making to your site to fix these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, it's a background image, referenced in `#content` (style.css line 105) - try replace it with a solid colour such as #FBFBFB. You'll also need to replace the background on `#content-top` (style.css line 100) with the same colour. I suggest you also add `border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;` to `#content-top` to round your corners in a similar way to how they were when using the background image.
2. The reason for your third box being shortert is because the first two posts have the `.first` class (see `#main-area .first` style.css line 108) which is pushing them down more than the third item. You could probably just remove this style altogether.

Answer (score 0):

To answer Problem 1, you are correct in that it is a background image. Both #content-top and #content have a background image. I'd suggest replacing them with your own modified version, or changing it to an actual background color.

For Problem 2, there is the following CSS rule at line 108 of style.css that is affecting the first two listings:

```
#main-area .first {
  padding-top: 28px !important;
}
```

This is overriding the normal top padding of 35px, which is making the first two listings higher than the third one. I'm sure there's a reason for it to exist in the theme, but typically CSS rules that use !important, which gives it precedence over other CSS rules, are a bad idea when used without good reason.